# How to get Magento Product URL from SOAP api

Tags: java, api, url, magento, xml-rpc

I'm beginner of Magento. I've been playing with Magento XML-RPC api.
I'm using Java to implement the api.
I was able to get required information about a product except the product url. I'm using product.info api method to get that information.

Product object as result of api request contains url_key, url_path. 
For example for product id: 35,
url_key=coalesce-functioning-on-impatience-t-shirt-small
url_paht=coalesce-functioning-on-impatience-t-shirt-small.html

Formulating product url as **STORE_HOST_URL + url_path** only works for certain products. Not for all the products.
How can reliably formulate product url using the information I have.

Is there a way to get product url with just the api methods and not tweaking the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

I use `http://freeshipping.in.ua/catalog/product/view/id/[PRODUCT_ID]` and this works.
Sure it's not the best way but I didn't find anything more usefull in API response...

Comment: Do you know if that works if the store has multiple storefronts? How would one test that?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with

> Formulating product url as STORE_HOST_URL + url_path only works for
>   certain products. Not for all the products.

**maybe you can try to reindex your url_path and url_key every product.**

1. empty your ../var/cache/*
2. fixing catalog URLS in - Admin > System > Cache management > Refresh Catalog Rewrites
3. Reindex URL - Admin > System > Index Management > check Catalog URL Rewrites > reindex;